# Bootstrap jsSocials PopOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, share, popover

How can I render text from jsSocial to popover?

This is html: in `data-content`, the code from `id=udostepnij` must be rendered

```
<a href="#" data-html="true" title="Udostępnij" data-toggle="popover"
data-trigger="focus" data-content="<div id='udostepnij'></div>">
    <span class="fa fa-share"></span> Udostępnij
</a>
```

**This is JavaScript:**

```
$("#udostepnij").jsSocials({
    showLabel: false,
    showCount: false,
    shares: ["twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "vkontakte", "pinterest", "stumbleupon", "whatsapp", "email", "reddit"],
    shareIn: "popup"
});
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

Does anyone know how to connect?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem:

Html:

```
<a href="#" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="Udostępnij"
    data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="<div id='udostepnij'></div><script>
    $('#udostepnij').jsSocials({
    showLabel: false,
    showCount: false,
        shares: ['twitter', 'facebook', 'googleplus', 'vkontakte', 'pinterest', 'stumbleupon', 'whatsapp', 'email', 'reddit', 'blogger'],
        shareIn: 'popup'
    });
    </script>"><span class="fa fa-share"></span> Udostępnij</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```